# Exclude current product and featured products from WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im using the following code (without the post__not_in parts) to query best rated products with wordpress woocommerce in single product view. I need to exclude the current post and feautred posts from the query. Any idea how to exclude both of them at the same time?

```
        $the_query = new WP_Query( array(           
            // Order by best rated products
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'post_status'  =>  'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => '-1',           
            'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
            'order'          => 'desc',
            'meta_key'       => '_wc_average_rating',
            'post__not_in'   => wc_get_featured_product_ids(),
            'post__not_in'   => array( $post->ID )          
        ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to merge the arrays? Not sure if you can use the post__not_in twice within the same query.

```
"post__not_in" => array_merge(array( $post->ID ), wc_get_featured_product_ids())
```

Comment: just tried your code - it does not exclude the current product... i entered the id as number and it works - but i dont know why your code do not work: `array_merge(array( '240' ), wc_get_featured_product_ids()), `

Comment: adding `global $post;` above the query did the trick. THX